# jsPlumb setContainer method nonexistent: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsplumb

I just started using jsPlumb and it seems really great but I'm getting some weird bugs with it and after reading around, people have said it might be to do with not setting a container.

The problem is, if I try and call `jsPlumb.setContainer($('.container'));` Inspect Element in Chrome gives me a TypeError:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Everything else I seem to do with jsPlumb seems to work (makeSource/makeTarget/etc.).

I looked at the API and it doesn't look like setContainer() has been removed or anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a dumb question, but I'll ask it anyway: have you loaded jQuery before you run this line of code?  It's the only other function on that line, might be what's causing the error.  Can you replicate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply, yes Jquery is loaded before jsPlumb. I also removed the jquery selector code and put it a line above the setContainer line to make sure it's working and console.log() shows it worked fine. I'll try it in jsfiddle now and report back.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jsPlumb?

Comment: Yes I tried a few different versions of jsPlumb as well as the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem,
I had a div with id="container"

and I solved with

**jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $('#container');**

Comment: That worked for me thanks - has the documentation been updated to say this is the way to do it?

Comment: I think it is a version issue. Latest version '2.2.9' works fine.